# GCC generates redundant code for repeated XOR of an array element

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization

GCC is giving me a hard time generating optimal assembly for following source code:

```
memset(X, 0, 16);
for (int i= 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    X[0] ^= table[i][Y[i]].asQWord;
}
```

`X` being an `uint64_t[2]` array, and
`Y` being an `unsigned char[16]` array, and
`table` being a double dimensional array of `union qword_t`:

```
union qword_t {
    uint8_t asBytes[8];
    uint64_t asQWord;
};

const union qword_t table[16][256] = /* ... */;
```

With options `-m64 -Ofast -mno-sse` it does unroll the loop, and **each xor with assignment** results in 3 instructions (thus overall number of instructions issued is 3 * 16 = 48):

```
movzx  r9d, byte ptr [Y + i]                   ; extracting byte
xor    rax, qword ptr [table + r9*8 + SHIFT]   ; xoring, SHIFT = i * 0x800
mov    qword ptr [X], rax                      ; storing result
```

Now, my understanding is that resulting X value could be accumulated in `rax` register throughout all 16 xors, and then it could be stored at `[X]` address, which could be achieved with these two instructions for each xor with assignment:

```
movzx  r9d, byte ptr [Y + i]                   ; extracting byte
xor    rax, qword ptr [table + r9*8 + SHIFT]   ; xoring, SHIFT = i * 0x800
```

and single storing:

```
mov    qword ptr [X], rax                      ; storing result
```

(In this case overall number of instructions is 2 * 16 + 1 = 33)

Why does GCC generate these redundant `mov` instructions? What can I do to avoid this?

P.S. C99, GCC 5.3.0, Intel Core i5 Sandy Bridge

Comment: FYI: not directly related to your question, but this site could be useful for you: https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: 2 questions:
Have you tried to compile it with -O2 and -O3? And the second question is can it be that `X` is defined as `volatile`?

Comment: @AlexLop 
1) -O3 produces literally the same assembly; -O2 does not even unroll the loop. 
2) No, `X` is not defined as volatile, it is `malloc`'-ed in top level functions and then passed by pointer.

Comment: It would be clearer and more effective (and portable) to simply accumulate the xor values in a temp, then *after* the loop do `X[0] ^= temp;`.  The optimizer doesn't necessarily know that the references to `X` aren't aliases to some of the other references within the loop.

Comment: gcc doesn't enable `-funroll-loops` even at `-Ofast`.  It is enabled with `-fprofile-use`, because then it has enough information to decide which loops to unroll.  Modern CPUs like compact code, esp. CPUs that have a uop-cache, so it's only a good idea for really hot loops.  Still, unrolling tiny loops a bit is good.  clang defaults to unrolling by 4 (at `-O3`).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens to your code if you replace the `memset` with a plain for loop? Seems this is related to "effective type" and pointer aliasing.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Redundant stores are usually down to aliasing; in this case gcc would be unable to prove to its satisfaction that the store to `X[0]` does not affect `table`. It makes a big difference *how* the variables are passed to the routine; if they are globals or members of the same larger struct then proving non-aliasing is easier.

[Example](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B1z+-Wall+-Wextra+-Werror',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXO4MDoAWAfAFCiSyKqYBO4A5gScTGGiHWAnEhPgIbUkATQDaARgBsAXQDczMCAD2YJAEcA7oupwA%2BhiQBvYkhNIYOABx6kfNACEAnhgRoRF2cdPmwGCQBZrWwBFAHUtODkAXzkWJRUNcOsMPgAjKARxaREAJgBWaTkTYgA3RRBuADMxAApvXwD9AA0cqQBKQ2IAWwROtAQMasaAGiQABhHJVrkKrSRqnCQQAF4xmUXUJEk1gGptkHajUyRm0akkAD0V5LSMkCkRUTupXGCw7SjiSOYcf2tm7I8pXKSAq2WqBy6PT6A2GYwmEimxBmgnmPkWK1GaxAGy2SF2%2Bw6RxOZ0uSGu6REdwelKkz1e4Q%2BkSAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

```
void f1(uint64_t X[2]) {
  memset(X, 0, 16);
  for (int i= 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    X[0] ^= table[i][Y[i]].asQWord;
  }
}

uint64_t X[2];
void f2() {
  memset(X, 0, 16);
  for (int i= 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    X[0] ^= table[i][Y[i]].asQWord;
  }
}
```

Here the store to `X[0]` is sunk out of the loop in `f2` but not in `f1`, because only in `f2` can gcc prove that `X` does not alias members of `table`.

Your workaround/fix could be to adjust how the parameters are passed, to use [the `restrict` specifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict), or to manually sink the store yourself.

Comment: terminology: apparently compiler devs call it "sinking" the store out of the loop.  It's the same idea as hoisting loop-invariant calculations out of a loop, but in the other direction.  Also: Intel-syntax output makes it much easier to see the stores in the godbolt output.  The QWORD PTR as the first operand stands out a lot more.  gcc fully unrolls in the version you linked so there's a wall-of-code effect, esp. for the AT&T syntax.  (I might have used `-fno-unroll-loops` for better human readability.).

Answer (score 9):

To avoid this, you could use this instead:

```
uint64_t v = 0;
for (int i= 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    v ^= table[i][Y[i]].asQWord;
}
X[0] = v;
X[1] = 0;
```

You can easily notice the generated instructions are sub-optimal in your case, however for different reasons gcc may not be able to determine that. (And in this case, gcc cannot determine that table will never access the same memory-region as X, as ecatmur explains more elaborately.)